# $f_n \to f$ uniformly if and only if $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We are also assuming $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$.

> I have already proved the direction assuming $f_n \to f$ uniformly, but I am now struggling to prove the other direction.

I have been given a hint saying to prove by contradiction, but I do not know how to use the negation of the definition of uniform convergence to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Assume that $f_n(y_n) \to f(y)$ whenever $y_n \to y$. If $f_n$ does not tend to $f$ uniformly there exists $\epsilon >0$, integers $1\leq n_1<n_2<...$ and a sequence $(x_k)$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})-f(x_{n_k})| >\epsilon $ for all $k$. Use the fact that $(x_k)$ has  a convergent subsequence to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: But do we not need to fix for a certain value e.g f(x) not f(x_nk). Because when we choose a convergent subsequence how do we not know that fn(xn) doesnt converge to it.

Comment: @DylanDijk You have to add and subtract $f(x)$ where $x$ is the limit of the subseqeunce: try to get $|f_{n_k}(x_{n_k})-f(x)| >\epsilon /2$.

Comment: Sorry im being stupid  will this require reverse triangle inequality or something

Comment: @DylanDijk Exactly! It requires reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Ok great thanks, and using the fact that we know f is continuous?